# Как сделать фотосъемку из консоли?

Tags: android, linux, консоль, камера

Собственно, такой вот вопрос. Как сделать фотосъемку из камеры Android?

Даже конкретно под Linux я нашёл лишь одну команду с ffmpeg:

```
 ~ # ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -r 1 -i /dev/video0 -f image2 image.png -t 1
```

Но в моём случае она не работает даже из под Kali Nethunter. Java я не хочу принципиально, да и пишу я консольный Linux бинарник.

Нашёл библиотеку /system/lib/android.hardware.camera.common.so и ещё парочку с похожим названием. Но вот как к ним правильно слинковаться, как их вообще в коде использовать - мне неясно.

Как сделать фото из консоли, посредством Linux бинарников, в Android?

Comment: adb утилита чем не решение?

Comment: а какую команду вводить? Да и это все равно консоль, просто из пк.

Comment: Нет. Не всё равно. Android имеет с Linux общего только ядро и то не на 100%.

Comment: написать приложение из 1 активности которое будет делать фото и командами adb из консоли запускать ее попутно сохраняя файл на ПК

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24748011/2101808 по адб подключиться к самому себе. но активити с камерой всеравно откроется.

Comment: 0andriy, Android - это по большей части Linux. Да и в /(system,vendor)/lib[64] есть хардварные библиотеки в духе libGLES.so и т д. Проблема может быть лишь в их... проприетарности. А так - достаем документацию, исходники, пишем прогу, линкуемся, делаем фото без мам, пап и Java. Да и, справедливости ради, имеют же сам Zygote (Java-машина) и vendor-ские бинарники имеют доступ к оборудованию, так чем user-end хуже?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если устройство подключено к компьютеру, то сделать это можно через [`adb`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb).

```bash
adb shell "am start -a android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" # открыть камеру
```

```bash
adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_CAMERA" # сфотографировать
```

Эти же команды можно выполнить с самого устройства, например, через терминал Termux, но вводить команды нужно без префикса adb shell:

```sh
am start -a android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE # открыть камеру
```

```sh
input keyevent KEYCODE_CAMERA # сфотографировать
```

Чтобы узнать больше про команду `am` (activity manager), наберите `adb shell am` или посмотрите в [документации](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#am).

Посмотреть, какие есть еще есть KeyEvent можно [здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent).